# Python Check if a 2-dimensional list contains numbers of another list

Tags: python, list

I want to know if a list contains numbers from a list of a list, but nothing I tried worked as I wanted. For example if a list of a list in list2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] is in list1 = [4, 5, 6, 7] it should print out True, because the numbers of list1 are a whole list from list2. So because list1 contains the numbers 4, 5, 6 the output should be True.

Here is what I tried

```
for i in range(len(list2)):
    if list1 in list2[i]:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

It prints out False two times (but I need it to print out True) and I get why

```
[1, 2, 3] in [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> False
```

Is there a way to avoid this?
Or should I just use strings since it works with them just fine?

Comment: `[2, 1, 3] in [1, 2, 3, 4]`, do you want this operation to return true or false? It contains the numbers but they aren't in the right order. does order matter?

Comment: @roganjosh but I want it to print out True. By adding a break it won't print out anything

Comment: This statement is incorrect: "For example if `list1 = [4,5,6,7]` is in `list2= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` it should print out `True`, because the numbers of `list1` are a list from `list2`." `list1` contains a `7` whereas all of the lists in `list2` do not.

Comment: So you want to know if any of the numbers in list1 occur in any of the lists in list2?

Comment: @stevenrumbalski sry I meant it should print out True if a list of list from list2 contains the numbers that are in list1

Comment: @markmeyer exactly

Comment: @Miray.  And none of them do.

Comment: `print('True' if any(s1.intersection(sublist) for s1 in [set(list1)] for sublist in list2) else 'False')` `.intersection()` is for overlap.  Change to `.issuperset()` if it needs to contain all elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding if a collection of items is a subset of another is more efficiently handled by a `set` than a `list`. Casting your list to a set allow quick lookup with the `set.issuperset` method.

```
list_of_lists = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
list1 = [4, 5, 6, 7]

list1_as_set = set(list1)

result = any(list1_as_set.issuperset(l) for l in list_of_lists) # True
```

The above code using `any` is equivalent to this solution using a for-loop.

```
for l in list_of_lists:
    if list1_as_set.issuperset(l):
        result = True
        break
else:
    result = False
```

Comment: Reverse the order and python casts the list to set for you: `list1_as_set.issuperset(l)`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Nice improvement